# Fixing UITableVIew lags

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift3

I was following [this](https://blog.uship.com/shippingcode/populating-uitableviewcells-asynchronously-to-fix-uitableview-lag/) tutorial how to avoid lags for `UITableView` but population data is not working well. Sometimes displays wrong data and does not change any more, or it display wrong then switch to the correct.

How could I solve this problem ??

This is needed class from tutorial

```
class SerialOperationQueue: OperationQueue
{
    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
    }
}
```

Then in `VehicleCell` class I have

```
let queue = SerialOperationQueue()
```

In model methods looks like from the tutorial :

Template :

```
func setSomething(vehicle: VehicleModel) -> String {
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.01)
        return "some string from model"
    }
```

In my `UITableViewDataSource` I have

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return vehiclesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "vehicleCell", for: indexPath) as! VehiclesCell   
    }
```

and `willDisplay`

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = cell as? VehiclesCell {
            configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath)
        }

cell.alpha = 0
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1, 0.1, 1)

        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            cell.alpha = 1
            cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1)
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }

private func configureCell(cell: VehiclesCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {

        cell.queue.cancelAllOperations()
        let operation: BlockOperation = BlockOperation()

        operation.addExecutionBlock {
            let vehicles = self.checkForVehicles(inSection: indexPath.section)
            let vehicle = vehicles[indexPath.row]
            let vehicleName = self.setVehicleName(vehicle: vehicle)
            let driverName = self.setDriverName(vehicle: vehicle)
            let topColor = self.setTopLineColor(vehicle: vehicle, colorView: cell.topColorView)
            let vehicleImage = self.setVehicleImage(vehicle: vehicle)
            let address = self.setAddress(vehicle: vehicle)
            let engineStatus = self.setEngineStatus(vehicle: vehicle)
            let hosStatus = self.setHosStatus(vehicle: vehicle)
            let speed = self.setSpeed(vehicle: vehicle)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                if operation.isCancelled { return }

                cell.vehicleNameLabel.text = vehicleName
                cell.driverNameLabel.text = driverName
                cell.topColorView = topColor
                cell.vehicleImageView.image = vehicleImage
                cell.localizationLabelView.text = address
                cell.engineLabel.text = engineStatus
                cell.hosStatusLabel.text = hosStatus
                cell.speedValueLabel.text = speed
            }
        }

        cell.queue.addOperation(operation)
    }
```

Does any one could explain me this behavior ? Why the cells are populated with wrong data and then when they get correct, they switching. Also they might stay like they are without switching to good data ?

What would be best option to solve that ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to change `DispatchQueue.main.async` to `DispatchQueue.main.sync`?

Comment: @t4nhpt Yes, I've tried. The same result.

Comment: use AsyncDisplayKit (Texture) to have perfectly scrolling table

Comment: @iWheelBuy I'll try it!

Comment: have you override the `prepareForReuse` function in `VehiclesCell `? I think that is the problem, and all this code is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have not override the [`prepareForReuse` function](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse) in `VehicleCell`.

Because the cells are being reused in a `UITableView` for smoother performance, it is reusing the cells in the tableView, instead of creating a new instance every time a new cell is needed.

When you do this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return vehiclesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "vehicleCell", for: indexPath) as! VehiclesCell   
}
```

instead of creating a new one, you dequeue a reusable cell with an identifier.

Therefore it is crucial, you override the `perpareForReuse` function. Looking at your interface of VehicleCell, it should be like the following:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.vehicleNameLabel.text = nil
    self.driverNameLabel.text = nil
    self.topColorView = nil
    self.vehicleImageView.image = nil
    self.localizationLabelView.text = nil
    self.engineLabel.text = nil
    self.hosStatusLabel.text = nil
    self.speedValueLabel.text = nil
}
```

And all this code in `willDisplayCell` is unneeded code, what does not work  and makes no sense at all.

**EDIT:**
I like the configureCell method, but not this playing with the queues. So i would recommend to do the following:

1. Delete `willDisplay` function.
2. Remove all this BlockOperation and queue related code from `configureCell`
3. Call `configureCell` from `cellForRowAt` and return the cell once it is set up

```

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: VehiclesCell = vehiclesTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "vehicleCell", for: indexPath) as! VehiclesCell
    self.configureCell(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath)
    return cell
}    

private func configureCell(cell: VehiclesCell, indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let vehicles = self.checkForVehicles(inSection: indexPath.section)
    let vehicle = vehicles[indexPath.row]
    let vehicleName = self.setVehicleName(vehicle: vehicle)
    let driverName = self.setDriverName(vehicle: vehicle)
    let topColor = self.setTopLineColor(vehicle: vehicle, colorView: cell.topColorView)
    let vehicleImage = self.setVehicleImage(vehicle: vehicle)
    let address = self.setAddress(vehicle: vehicle)
    let engineStatus = self.setEngineStatus(vehicle: vehicle)
    let hosStatus = self.setHosStatus(vehicle: vehicle)
    let speed = self.setSpeed(vehicle: vehicle)

    cell.vehicleNameLabel.text = vehicleName
    cell.driverNameLabel.text = driverName
    cell.topColorView = topColor
    cell.vehicleImageView.image = vehicleImage
    cell.localizationLabelView.text = address
    cell.engineLabel.text = engineStatus
    cell.hosStatusLabel.text = hosStatus
    cell.speedValueLabel.text = speed
}
```

```

Comment: Alright! I've ovverriden the method which u point. So basically I should not use this code ? And set the info about cell properties in `cellForRowAt` ?

Comment: Most of the optimisation code you got from the tutorial is pure uselessness. I have edited my answer, how to update `cellForRowAt`.

Comment: OK, and what about animations - they are going to `cellForRowAt` ?

Comment: where do you have animations here? in `setEngineStatus` for example?

Comment: OK, sry does not post it! Ill eded in a second!

Comment: Edit completed.

Comment: ignore that too, you do not need it. Just set the strings straight away in `cellForRowAt`

Comment: Alright, but without async taks, scrolling view is painfull

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143378/discussion-between-dirtydanee-and-derpyunknown).

Comment: BTW, why the downvote? The question was is the data being duplicated in cells, and the answer is clearly the `prepareForReuse` was not overriden.